# MVC 4 CREATE TABLE permission denied in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am new to web development. I am trying to follow the MVC tutorial for Movie DB using MVC 4 and EF Code First given at the URL below.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

I created a simple project with the internet template and created a model mimicking a actual table in my DB as given in the tutorial. I then created a new model for a table based on my existing DB and thats when the problem started. Everything worked when the web.config was pointing to the localdb.

I changed the web.config to point to my actual database to see how the code works and for some reason which numerous users have posted, i get the DB permission error. Here is my model.

```
namespace MVCTest.Models
{
    public class ProjectID
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID{ get; set; }
        public int TEMP_ID { get; set; }
        public string STATUS { get; set; }
        public string DESC{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my context. Controller was created based on this model and context.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MVCTest.Models
{
    public class MVCDBContext : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, add the following
        // code to the Application_Start method in your Global.asax file.
        // Note: this will destroy and re-create your database with every model change.
        // 
        //System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MvcMovie.Models.MvcMovieContext>());

        public MVCDBContext()
          : base("name=MVCDBContext")
          //  : base("Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=True;")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProjectID> ProjectIDs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The table is already there and I just wanted to do RUD operations to the actual SQL table as opposed to the one in the Local DB.

I have tried many options listed in stackoverflow and many other websites and nothing worked for me. The only option I have remaining is to go through EF Data First but I wanted to see if anybody has suggestions before I scrap this project and go to that.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'DBNAME'.

Source Error:

Line 19:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 20:         {
Line 21:             return View(db.ProjectIDs.ToList());
Line 22:         }
Line 23: 

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'DBNAME'.]
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1754082
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295874
    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout) +280
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +405
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement) +224
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement) +55
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +169
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +42
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto) +1025
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading) +320
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading) +64
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +538
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +59
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +897
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update() +33
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +456
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext) +173
    System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(Boolean skipExistsCheck) +241
    System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +396
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6() +67
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +110
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +273
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +31
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +143
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +270
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +123
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +42
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +137
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +38
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +99
    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
    MVCtest.Controllers.ProjectIDsController.Index() in c:\Users\n228322\Data\MVCtest\MVCtest\Controllers\ProjectIDsController.cs:21
    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
    System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +435
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +50
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +75
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +44
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +139
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +126
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +323
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +139
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +68
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +136
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9633216
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the full text of your error to the question? It's difficult for people to try and help you if we don't know exactly what it is that's wrong!

Comment: Appreciate any feedback or suggestions. I edited the post with the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Upon invoking my Google-fu I found [this potentially applicable thread](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.devel.dotnet.umbraco/2006-02/msg00427.html). For posterity (in case the thread is ever deleted or is otherwise inaccessible), here are the relevant bits (trimmed greatly for brevity):

> Hello all I am currently trying to set up Umbraco, I am at the
>   step of installing the database but i get the following error

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'umbraco'.

[SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'umbraco'.]
```

Another site user responded as follows:

> Are you sure you have permissions to create tables on your database?
>   You can check this by login in on your database under the same account as in your connectionstring. Then try to Create a Table, if that doesn't work fix the
>   usercredentials for that account.

**Note:** if you've followed the tutorial to the letter your `connectionString` should be set to the following in your *Web.config* file:

```xml
<add name="MovieDBContext" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>
```

Following this suggestion, the OP replied:

> Thanks for the response. I found the problem. Right click the
>   database --> Permissions --> Select create table tickbox.

Could you follow these steps and see if it resolves your issue? If it doesn't then I'm afraid you'll have to wait for someone with some expertise in this area to come along and help you out, as all I can do is hit up Google for the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, in the place where I work, the only access I have is to create Stored Procedures and that too under my schema even in DEV. This should be something simple. Not all companies allow users with DB modify access.

Comment: @Web_developer_beginner Well without the necessary permissions granted there's really no way I can see this working. It seems strange to me that a company would have someone working on a product but disallow any DB schema changes. Just seems counterproductive. Anyway, if you don't have permissions you either need to have them granted to you, or have a DBA create the table so you can start using it.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry. May be I was not clear before. The table is already in the DB. I just need to be able to access it without the code trying to create it.